# What is "@" in Next.js paths?

Tags: next.js

I am new to Next.js and and I am seeing an '@' character in file paths. Example:

```
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'
```

and even in jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The Next.js documentation or any other source does not provide the definition of this "@" character. I am seeing this '@' for the first time in paths. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The `@` character is used to define path alias in `Next.js`. This is provided by `webpack` which is the module bundler used by Next.js.

In the example you provided, the paths property defines an alias for the components directory, using the @ symbol as a prefix. The asterisk * is a wildcard character that allows you to specify a pattern for matching file paths.

With this configuration, you can import components from the components directory using the @ alias, like `import Footer from '@/components/Footer';`

This will be resolved to the components/Footer.js file, based on the path mapping defined in the jsconfig.json file

Documentation can be found here: [Absolute Imports and Module Path Aliases](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/absolute-imports-and-module-aliases#module-aliases)